# IBM cognitive labs login

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, ibm-connections

I cannot login to IBM cognitive labs. I have already logged in to cognitive class
Still cannot login to cognitive labs I Cannot see login button while clicking on login button, I have attached also attached the image below.Here is the link for [Cognitive lab](https://labs.cognitiveclass.ai/login) Please let me know why if anyone know how to login or find any solution.
p.s: I have watched the IBM's Video for login and also asked them for help but no response...

[Image of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRIn0.png)

Comment: Have you tried in a private window or different browser? The login button is showing fine for me, I got a 503 error first time I tried to connect but second time went through.

Comment: yes,but no luck.

Comment: looks like a browser issue. Button doesn't show up in chrome but works in firefox.

Comment: @umerjamal Which version of Chrome do you have? And do you have any extensions that may stop the button from showing up?

Answer (score 0):

Bad gateway error caused by hardware failure due to extremely high periods of activity. 
Log out and log back is their solution for now.

You can refer to this article. https://support.labs.cognitiveclass.ai/knowledgebase/articles/1812817-bad-gateway-502-or-503-error